# java arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, c++, matrix, arraylist

hi when I wanted to have something like vector of vectors (elements shall be ordered of course) I thought of having arraylist of arraylists but in C++ i would do this to access the element `v.at(i).at(j)=5;` and when i need to add new element `v.at(i).push_back(value);` 
so how do i do this in java ? because I can only access the outer arraylist but i don't know how to add new elements...and is there a better way to simulate C++ vector of vectors in java ??

p.s (it's not a matrix 3*2 for ex but each arraylist may have different size)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare an `ArrayList` of `ArraList<Integer>`s:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> v = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
v.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

v.get(0).add(new Integer(5));
v.get(0).add(new Integer(10));
System.out.println(v.get(0).get(0)); // => 5
System.out.println(v.get(0).get(1)); // => 10
```

Comment: You should not use `new Integer(..)`. Let Java autobox it. Or, least preferred, use `Integer.valueOf(..)`

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

// initialize the inner lists
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    l.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());


// now you can use it as you would like
l.get(i).add(5);
l.get(i).set(0, 3);
```

Comment: Stop using the Vector class! Sry being rude but Vector is "deprecated" for like 5 years.

Comment: I know, I just edited and changed from ArrayList to Vector. I tought he needed a synchronized version...

Comment: Changed it back to ArrayList (now using the List interface - much cleaner).

Answer (score 1):

You can have `List<List<Integer>>` in Java. accessing the element would be `list.get(i).get(j)`. Adding, likewise: `list.get(i).add(var)`. Also take a look at the `set(..)` method

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on previous comments yet so i'll post it here.

As netbeans says it's not necessary to write

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< Integer>> v = new ArrayList< ArrayList< Integer>>();
```

because the arguments are redundant; instead you can write:

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< Integer>> v = new ArrayList<>();
```